# flask opening html in html

Tags: html, flask, ipynb

In my ipynb file I open html like this and it is working:
`from IPython.display import IFrame html_file_path = '1.html' IFrame(html_file_path, width=800, height=600)`
Then I make html from my notebook and open it using Flask
And then I get this kind of mistake in a place where I have to have 1.html:
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

1.html is in my templates folder.
What should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.